# SQL Server 2005 on Windows Server 2012 R2 Install Question

Tags: sql-server-2005

Can I Install SQL Server 2005 on Windows Server 2012 R2 ?

Thanks !

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can be answered by reading the MS official SQL-Server requirements.

Comment: I'm sure the OP knows that, but is trying to circumvent the KB article because he or someone else doesn't want to follow the recommended upgrade path....

Comment: The documentation states this configuration is not supported - the keyword here is supported.  The OP is not asking if it is supported, but rather if it is possible.  I too want to know if this is possible, not for a production environment but for development I need to do, and this configuration is all I have.  I think its a valid question.

Answer (score 2):

That is an unsupported configuration.  Please see [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2681562) explaining this.

> SQL Server 2005 (the release version and service packs) and earlier versions of SQL Server are not supported on Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2012, Windows 8.1, or Windows 8. You will receive a warning in the Action Center if Windows 8.1 or Windows 8 detects an instance of SQL Server 2005.

Comment: This answer assumes the OP asked if SQL 2005 is supported on Server 2012 R2.  The OP never uses the word supported, he merely asks if its possible.